# C# WPF Method call executes synchronous but not when called in explicit Thread

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having a problem running my `SaveToFile` method in a `Thread`. 
Synchronously it works fine. 
I need to save a simple UML diagram containing some classes and such to XML.

I have a SaveLoadController:

```
 public void SaveToFile(ItemsCollection d, string path)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
        {
            XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ItemsCollection), new Type[] { typeof(Item), typeof(ClassViewModel) });
            s.Serialize(fs, d);
        }
    }
```

And here is the problem:

```
public void SaveAsToFile()
    {
        FileDialog fd = new SaveFileDialog();
        bool? result = fd.ShowDialog();
        if (result.HasValue && result.Value)
        {
            //Thread t = new Thread(() => saveLoadController.SaveToFile(this.Items, fd.FileName));
            saveLoadController.SaveToFile(this.Items, fd.FileName);
        }
    }
```

It works as it is now, but if I use the `Thread t...` line, no file is saved.
Can someone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: You need to `start()` that thread. Otherwise it's not doing anything. I highly recommend reading on`ThreadPool` and `Task Parallel Library` though. They're much better suited for things like this.

Comment: Ah of course. I've heard `Task.Run` should be better suited, but for this project (School project) we've been told to use explicit `Thread`s for some reason.

Comment: Using threads here is questionable. If you just fire-and-forget the thread, you can't safely modify the given `ItemsCollection` in `this.Items` until the thread/saving has completed. What kind of problem are you trying to solve where introducing a thread is the solution?

Comment: In this case it's just to make the execution of the save process non-blocking. I know it's not much of an issue here, but it's more of a demonstration. Would another approach be more desirable?